# DataTransformer with collection form return entity with null id

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I try to make a form with a collection which has an autocomplete system.
It's possible to add or remove items.
[image]

If the "Actes" exists, you click on the proposal and the two other fields are filled automatically. I added a hidden field "num" which is filled by the id of the entity automatically too.
It's possible the "Actes" doesn't exist and need to be created. In this case, hidden field "num" won't be filled.

I had a DataTansformer on "num" field. After submit, it returns the correct entity but in the controller after binding (`$form->bind($request)`) the entity has null ID and is created another time in database.

My principal form :

```
class FamilyType extends AbstractType
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')
                ->add('acts', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new ActType($this->manager),
                    'label' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ))
        ;

    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Catalogue\MainBundle\Entity\Family'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'catalogue_mainbundle_family';
    }
}
```

ActType.php:

```
class ActType extends AbstractType
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title','text')
                ->add('description', 'textarea', array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'row' => 5
                    )
                ))
                ->add('typeProcessus', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'CatalogueMainBundle:TypeProcessus',
                    'choice_label' => 'name'
                ))
                ->add('num', 'hidden', array(
                    'invalid_message' => "Ce numéro n'est pas valide",
                    'mapped' => false
                ))
        ;

        $builder->get('num')->addModelTransformer(new ActToNumberTransformer($this->manager));
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Catalogue\MainBundle\Entity\Act'
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'catalogue_mainbundle_act';
    }
}
```

My DataTansformer :

```
class ActToNumberTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function transform($act) {
        if(null == $act){
            return '';
        }

        return $act->getId();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($actNumber) {
        if(!$actNumber){
            return;
        }

        $act = $this->manager->getRepository("CatalogueMainBundle:Act")->find($actNumber);

        if(null == $act){
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('Acte "%s" inexistant', $actNumber));
        }

        return $act;
    }
}
```

When I dump `$form->get('acts')->getData()` in my controller, entites have null ID. I don't understand when ID is removed. Probably because it's consider like a new item in collection.